# Java WebService Security

Tags: java-metro-framework

i implementing Java WebService with JAX-WS and now need to secure my webservice with username and password when requester call webService , i need solution that send username and password 
on Header of SOAP and webservice get this and Authenticate user.
do you have any idea for implementing this on standard way ?

---

now i can send username and password with soap header , but i need solution that encrypt SOAP header and content , do you have standard way for this work ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bag o' links, incoming:

- [How do I do basic authentication in JAX-WS?](http://jax-ws.java.net/faq/index.html#auth)
- [Example: Basic Authentication with JAX-WS (The Java EE 6 Tutorial)](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19226-01/820-7627/bnccv/index.html)
- [Metro Guide - Security Mechanisms](http://metro.java.net/guide/Security_Mechanisms.html)
- [What is the best prctice for using security in JAX-WS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776038/what-is-the-best-prctice-for-using-security-in-jax-ws)
- [JAX-WS and BASIC authentication, when user names and passwords are in a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1613212/jax-ws-and-basic-authentication-when-user-names-and-passwords-are-in-a-database)
- [JAX-WS authentication against a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/377901/jax-ws-authentication-agains-a-database)

There is a ton of info out there already. Have you read *anything?*